# Fit textbox to content in Keynote

Tags: keynote

When you create a new textbox in Keynote, it automatically resizes as you type.  Once you manually change the width of the box, it will lock the width.  How can you change the behavior back to automatically resize?  (An obvious workaround is to create a new textbox and paste the text in there)